# Cannot cast response from Hibernate to List of objects

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Hibernate outputs **list of list of values** instead of **list of objects**

I referred to some samples which leads me to the same way that I have implemented already. 
[Hibernate sample](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm)

Here my problem,

```
public List<Loan> getLoans(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    factory =  DbSessionManager.getSessionFactory("core");
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<Loan> loans = null;
    try{
        session.createCriteria(Loan.class).list();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("getLoansBetweenDates").setDate("fromDate", fromDate).setDate("toDate", toDate);
        loans = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = loans.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Loan loan = (Loan) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(loan.getLoanId());
        }
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException he) {
        if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        he.printStackTrace();
    }
    return loans;
}
```

Error when tried to cast to Loan:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [TM_Service] in context with path [/TM_Service] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to model.core.Loan] with root cause java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to model.core.Loan
at utility.LoanManager.getLoans(LoanManager.java:75)
at controller.LoanController.getLoan(LoanController.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In other words, the above code when exposed as a web service, without any casting, I get the following output. Looks like a **list of - list of values**

```
[
 [  
  "137",
  15,
  "open",
  null
 ],
 [  
  "147",
  17,
  "open",
  null
 ],
 [  
  "157",
  16,
  "open",
  null
 ]
]
```

I'm expecting the following output,

```
[  
 {  
  "loanId":"137",
  "customerId":15,
  "status":"open",
  "comments":null
 },
 {  
  "loanId":"147",
  "customerId":17,
  "status":"open",
  "comments":null
 },
 {  
  "loanId":"157",
  "customerId":16,
  "status":"open",
  "comments":null
 }
]
```

Pojo

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
  @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "getLoansBetweenDates",
        query = "select * from tm_core.loan where tm_core.loan.loan_id in "
                    + "(select tm_core.loan.loan_id from tm_core.loan inner join tm_core.transaction " + 
                        "on tm_core.loan.loan_id = tm_core.transaction.loan_id " + 
                        "where " + 
                            "loan_status = 'open' and " + 
                            "category = 'principal' and " + 
                            "date >= :fromDate and " +
                            "date <= :toDate " +
                    "order by date asc)"
  )
})
@Entity
@Table(name="loan")
public class Loan implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @Column(name="loan_id", nullable=false, unique=true)
  String loanId;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference
  Customer customer;
  @Column(name="loan_status")
  String loanStatus;
  @Column(name="comments")
  String comments;
}
```

Should I implement object mapper which I feel as messy option? Is there any way to tweak the Hibernate output so that the response will looks like **list of objects**, instead of a **'list of - list of values'**

[My project source code](https://github.com/liwevire/TM_Service/)

Comment: It seems Hibernate treats the `select *` as indication you want values. Have you tried omitting the `select *` in the named query.

Comment: Getting syntax error for that. Shall I try converting the Native SQL to HQL, will that help?

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that. Try HQL/JPQL.

Comment: could not resolve property: Transaction of: model.core.Loan for the following code `select lo from  model.core.Loan lo join lo.Transaction tr on lo.loanId = tr.Loan.loanId where lo.loan_status = 'open' and category = 'principal' and date = :date order by date asc`

Comment: `Path expected for join!
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:368)` for the following code `select lo from model.core.Loan lo join lo.Transaction tr on lo.loanId = tr.Loan.loanId where lo.loan_status = 'open' and category = 'principal' and date = :date order by date asc`. When I tried to solve this error, I get the error mentioned in the previous comment!

Comment: I have tried the other way around also. But I got this `could not resolve property: Loan of: model.core.Transaction [select lo from model.core.Transaction tr join tr.Loan lo on lo.loanId = tr.Loan.loanId where lo.loan_status = 'open' and category = 'principal' and date = :date order by date asc]`